# MAC Jupyter Notebook add Graphviz to Path, Graphviz ExecutableNotFound: How to add Graphviz to path?

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, visualization, graphviz

I am having problems running graphviz in Jupyter notebook.

I am using the conda environment and have installed graphviz using brew and Conda.

I ran the command `which dot` to see where graphviz's path is and got this back

```
/anaconda3/bin/dot
```

I have edited my path file so that it looks like this

```
/anaconda3/bin/
/usr/local/bin/
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

However I still end up getting the errors

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot': 'dot'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tsvg'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

I know I am doing something wrong, but am unsure how to get this too work.

I am trying to run this code in Jupyter Notebook but am getting the above errors, the strange things is that graphviz works in the command line, but not in Jupyter notebook.

```
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right      

from lolviz import *

root = Tree(100)
treeviz(root)
```

If anyone knows how to solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing graphviz via homebrew instead (rather than pip from anaconda) as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/issues/36). Try uninstalling it and reinstalling with homebrew. You should see

```sh
$ which dot
/usr/local/bin/dot
```

rather than the anaconda path you currently see.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Graphviz via Anaconda but a function calling `dot` caused the same error. Adding `/opt/anaconda3/bin` to my path did not help either. Following Elias' answer, I just copied `dot` to my `/usr/local/bin` and removed `/opt/anaconda3/bin` from my path. It works now!